# How to send data from a dynamically added form to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have created a dynamic form that has data from a MySQL database and it works great. Problem is, I don't know how to get the ajax to read the form.

**Assuming that below code is a single form:**

```
<form>
    <!-- input type content here -->
</form>
```

**It's equivalent ajax code would be:**

```
$(document).ready(function(

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: $("#frm").serialize();
       //insert more code...
});

))
```

**What if my form was dynamically added like this:**

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    <!-- insert code for dynamic grid see sample link [here][1]  
    <form>
       <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1">
       <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2">
       <input type="radio" name="rate" value="3">

       <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['p_name']?>"
       <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['p_price']?>"
    </form>

}?>
```

How would I get those data if my form was created dynamically? Do I even have to add an array symbol to my form e.g `<form name="myFrm[]"` ?. If it is how would I even call it to the ajax?

Comment: *How* the form was created doesn't matter.  It exists in the DOM.  So long as you can write a selector to find it, when you need it, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Its the same whether the form is built dynamically or statically. `.serialize()` picks up any `<input>` with a name that exists in the specified `<from>`

Comment: Last I remember `.serialize()` does not include input type submit. Don't know if this is still true

Comment: @frz3993 it may, provided you give it a name attribute.

Comment: Ah, it is actually the button type submit https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ .

Answer (score 1):

Please try below solution.

Set form id dynamically with auto increment variable.

```
<?php $i=1; while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
<!-- insert code for dynamic grid see sample link [here][1]  
<form id="frm<?php echo $i;?>">
   <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1">
   <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2">
   <input type="radio" name="rate" value="3">

   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['p_name']?>">
   <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['p_price']?>">
  <input type="button" name="button" value="click" class="common_submit_btn">
</form>
$i++; 
}?>
```

Below JavaScript code for getting dynamic forms ID in ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(
  $(".common_submit_btn").click(function(){
  //here you can get submitted form data in console.
  console.log($('#'+$(this).closest('form').attr('id')).serialize());
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    data: $('#'+$(this).closest('form').attr('id')).serialize(),
   //insert more code...
 });
});
});
```

Comment: there's always this kind of bug., not sure what that is but whenever i click on a radio button for instance on the given code above, it stays exactly at the value of 3, and i can't seem to click on another group of radio button which was created dynamically.,

Comment: oops nvm that., it actually works with button but let's remove the input type for the moment., how would we handle that event using just the radio button?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your JavaScript says:

- when the document is ready:

  - do something with the form

Therefore before your user has even entered data you've run that `$.ajax` command, you probably want to wrap it with some sort of event listener like change or maybe add a submit button and submit the data.

Comment: This is a valid point, but it does not answer the OP's actual question. If you add something that addresses the actual question it would be better, otherwise this is really just a comment